# 'Unknown MySQL server host' when attaching to MySQL container

Tags: mysql, database, docker, containers, volumes

I am trying to attach to my MySQL container to ensure the data I wanted to transfer to the volume and container is being applied correctly. Ideally I was trying to do this by attaching via CLI through the Docker Desktop software. However trying to run `mysql` I get a *Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1:3306' (-2)* error. I have tried changing the MYSQL_HOST variable to 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0, and localhost.

Here is a copy of my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:  
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    env_file: compose.env    
    volumes: 
        - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
volumes:
  db-data:
```

**UPDATE:** So I removed the MYSQL_HOST environment variable from compose.env and now I can attach and query data. Not sure why this was a conflict though.

Comment: -hmysql does not work?

Comment: Haven't tried starting via CLI just running ```docker-compose up --build```